# Can Woodin's fast function forcing kill Shelah cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

**Definition 1.** An uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ is Shelah if for every function $f:\kappa\rightarrow \kappa$ there exists a transitive class $M$ and a non-trivial elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow M$ such that $^\kappa M\subseteq M$, $crit(j)=\kappa$ and $V_{j(f)(\kappa)}\subseteq M$.

**Definition 2.** Woodin's fast function forcing on $\kappa$ consists of partial functions $p$ from $\kappa$ to $\kappa$ ordered by inclusion such that:

- The domain of $p$ consists of inaccessible cardinals $\lambda <\kappa$ which are closed under $p$, namely for every $\lambda, \theta\in dom(p)$ if $\theta<\lambda$ then $p(\theta)<\lambda$.
- For every $\lambda\in dom(p)$ we have $|dom(p)\cap \lambda|<\lambda$

**Remark.** Following [Joel's comment below](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287871/can-woodins-fast-function-forcing-kill-shelah-cardinals#comment712466_287871), it is worth mentioning that the above definition is NOT the only variant of fast function forcing. There are other versions with slightly different properties. For a more complete argument along these lines see [Joel's answer in this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/272233/82843).

On one hand, preserving Shelah cardinals through lifting arguments often needs dominating the corresponding functions $f:\kappa\rightarrow \kappa$ by functions in the ground model.

On the other hand, we know that the fast function forcing $\mathbb{P}_{\kappa}$ adds a very fast (and so non-dominatable) function of this type into the universe (i.e. the fast function) and simultaneously [fails to satisfy $\kappa$-cc property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272223/does-fast-function-forcing-really-have-kappa-knaster-property) which is a usual condition for providing dominating functions in the ground model.

> Thus it is somehow natural to expect that (all variants of) Woodin's fast function forcing can kill Shelah cardinals. Is it true? Any concrete example?

Comment: The fast function forcing works better, with nicer factor properties, if you insist that $|p\upharpoonright\lambda|<\lambda$ for every inaccessible cardinal, rather than just $\lambda\in\text{dom}(p)$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for reminding this fact, Joel! I edited the original post accordingly.

Comment: What about the following idea:
Assume it preserve the Shelahness of $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is the least Shelah cardinal. Let $f: \kappa \to \kappa$ be the fast function added by the forcing $\mathbb{P}$. Let $G$ be the generic filter. By our assumption, there exists $j: V[G] \to M$ such that $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences (in $V[G]$), $crit(j)=\kappa$ and $V[G]_{j(f)(\kappa)} \subset M.$ Let us force below $(\kappa, wt^V(\kappa)+\omega) \in j(\mathbb{P}),$ where $wt^V(\kappa)$ is the witnessing number of $\kappa$ in $V$.

Comment: This implies $V[G]_{wt^V(\kappa)+\omega} \subset M,$ in particular, the results of [An Easton like theorem in the presence of Shelah cardinals](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/Papers/An%20Easton%20like%20theorem%20in%20the%20presence%20of%20Shelah%20Cardinals.pdf) show that $\kappa$ is not the least Shelah cardinal in $V[G]$. But the forcing creates no new Shelah cardinals, so $\kappa$ is not the least Shelah cardinal in $V$ as well, a contradiction.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Thanks! Your approach sounds promising! Could you please add it as an answer?

Comment: @MortezaAzad I will wait to hear from some expert if the argument is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Assume it preserve the Shelahness of $\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is th eleast Shelah cardinal.
 Let $f: \kappa \to \kappa$ be the fast function added by the forcing $\mathbb{P}$. Let $G$ be the generic filter.

By our assumption, there exists $j: V[G] \to M$ such that $M$ is closed under $\kappa$-sequences 
(in $V[G]$), $crit(j)=\kappa$ and $V[G]_{j(f)(\kappa)} \subset M.$

Let us force below $(\kappa, wt^V(\kappa)+\omega) \in j(\mathbb{P}),$ where $wt^V(\kappa)$
is the witnessing number of $\kappa$ in $V$. This implies $V[G]_{wt^V(\kappa)+\omega} \subset M,$ in particular,
 the results of [An Easton like theorem in the presence of Shelah cardinals](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/~golshani/Papers/An%20Easton%20like%20theorem%20in%20the%20presence%20of%20Shelah%20Cardinals.pdf) 
show that $\kappa$ is not the least Shelah cardinal in $V[G]$. But the forcing creates no new Shelah cardinals,
 so $\kappa$ is not the least Shelah cardinal in $V$ as well, a contradiction.

Comment: (+1) Sounds correct! Thanks for posting, Mohammad!

Comment: I don't understand the argument: do you start by assuming that $j$ is some embedding in $V[G]$ or do you assume that this embedding extends an embedding from $V$? In the first case, you might not be able to pick $j(f)(\kappa)$ to be any value that you want. It shouldn't be an issue that the second case always occurs. The forcing admits a gap below $\kappa$ so any elementary embedding in $V[G]$ extends one from the ground model.

Comment: I think Hamkins work shows that any embedding in the extension is extension of some embedding from the ground model